# Entity Framework DateTime ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, datetime, asp.net-web-api

I am using web api 2 with entity framework v 6.0.0 . I have a table that contains a date column called StudyGroupStartDate so i used the data annotations like this:

```
    [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
    public DateTime? StudyGroupStartDate { get; set; }
```

And this is how it is saved in the database : 
7/20/2015.
However when i retrieve it and display it is returned like this :
2015-07-20T00:00:00 (I want it to be like how it's saved in the database)

Note that i am not using MVC , i created an empty web application and chose web api so i am just using controllers that were generated using the model.And this is an example of my controller.

```
    // GET: api/StudyGroups
    public List<StudyGroup> GetStudyGroups()
    {
        return db.StudyGroups.Where(a=>a.IsDeleted==false).ToList();
    }
```

I just changed the generated code of the GET request to retrieve the result as a list with a condition of is_deleted to be false.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what really is your issue. You have to format the `DateTime` in your front-end, i.e., parse this date time value (2015-07-20T00:00:00) and then format as you want.

Other possibility is cast the `DateTime` as `String`, doing something like this:

```C#
// GET: api/StudyGroups
public List<Object> GetStudyGroups()
{
    return db.StudyGroups.Where(a=>a.IsDeleted==false)
      .Select(it => new { studyGroup = it, it.StudyGroupStartDate.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") })
      .ToList();
}
```

There's a third possibility, but that is too tricky I think: you can create a `String` property to return only this field as `String`, with the format you want (see below):

```
[Column(TypeName = "Date")]
public DateTime? StudyGroupStartDate { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "DateStr")]
public String StudyGroupStartDateStr { 
  get {
    return StudyGroupStartDate.ToString("M/dd/yyyy");
  }
}
```

Remember: in this case, you need to use/show the `DateStr` column, instead of the `Date` column.

Comment: my issue is that the StudyGroupStartDate column is of type date and when i retrieve it , it is returned as DateTime (notice 2015-07-20T00:00:00(which i don't want) vs 7/20/2015 (which i want) ) , and i tried your solution but it's giving me an error : invalid anonymous type member declarator

Comment: As I say, you are getting this format because this is default format of `DateTime.ToString` method and in this case, you need to parse and then, format the `DateTime` with the format you want. Is that possible in you situation?

Comment: I put another solution in my answer, check again.

Comment: It didn't work because it says that the StudyGroupStartDate is ambiguous , i ended up handling it in the front end.

Comment: Sorry, I have copied-pasted the code and didn't change the new property's name, you need to change the second `StudyGroupStartDate` to `StudyGroupStartDateStr `.

Comment: @lssilveira you should be able to use the [DataFormat( ... ] attribute